# Gimp perspective tool is not actually transforming

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, gimp

I've uploaded a screenshot below to illustrate the problem. I've dragged a jpeg into Gimp, clicked on the perspective tool, and then attempted to use it...but as you can see, it's not actually transforming the image. Why is this so?

*<sub>Click to expand image</sub>*

[image]

Comment: Sorry, uploaded now :)

Answer (score 7):

That's because you inadvertently selected the **"Perspective Clone"** tool instead of **"Perspective"**.